# C# Determine if Dictionary Contains All of a Set of Values

Tags: c#, dictionary, arraylist

I have the following dictionary :

```
Dictionary<string, ArrayList> vertices = new Dictionary<string, ArrayList>();
vertices.Add("Key1",stringarray1);
vertices.Add("Key2",stringarray2);
vertices.Add("Key3",stringarray3);
```

Now I'm trying to figure out is how to check for each of the dictionary's other keys (like `"Key2"` or `"Key3"`) if their values contain one or all of the values from `"Key1"`'s values (`ArrayList`), but its not working. This might be very straight forward, but I could not get it

```
var values = (ArrayList)vertices["Key1"];
foreach (var val in vertices)
{
    if (val.Key != "Key1" && val.Value.Contains(values))
    {
        //do something here
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure if it's your problem but string comparison by default is case sensitive.  use `val.Key != "Key1" && `

Comment: What is the data you store in the arrayList? any specific reason you are using this structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing the wrong thing to the `Contains`. `Contains` is supposed to receive an item to look for in the collection but you are passing an entire collection. Because you are using `ArrayList`, where the items are stored as `object` you are not receiving a compile time error but it just doesn't work (and the items are compared using `object`'s compare which is to check references.

You can use Linq to do it this way:

```
string key = "Key1";
var key1Collection = vertices[key].Cast<object>().ToList();
foreach(var item in vertices.Where(x => x.Key != key ))
{
    //If you want that all the items of the collection will be in the "Key1" collection:
    if(item.Value.Cast<object>().All(x => key1Collection.Contains(x))
    {
         //Do stuff
    }

    //Or if you want that at least 1 of the items of the collection will be in the "Key1" collection:
    if(item.Value.Cast<object>().Any(x => key1Collection.Contains(x))
    {
         //Do stuff
    }
}
```

*If you change your data structure from `ArrayList` to `List<TheTypeOfYourItems>` then you won't need all the `.Cast<object>`*

Comment: I need to figure out which exact Key is returning true and which is not., since i need to do some manual operation. Can you help please ?

Comment: @Srini - Also what is the reason you are using `ArrayList`? What is the actual data you are putting there?

Comment: Thanks , that worked like charm. I have modified my data structure to Linked list now, chose wrong one before.

Comment: @Srini - I think you can just go for a normal `List<SomeType>` - most straight forward and simple :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass a collection into contains method but rather a singular element. So you need to iterate over the elements in the key1 array and check if the other array also contains it.

```
var key1Val = vertices["key1"];
 foreach (var val in vertices)
        {
            if(val.Key != "key1")
            {
               bool exist = false;
               foreach (var element in val.Value) {
                      if(key1Val.Contains(element)){
                            exist = true;
                            break;
                      }
                 }
                  if(exist){        /*do stuff*/}
                //do something here
            }
        }
```

Comment: the answer you marked as helpful has the exact same time complexity as my answer so I'm a bit confused as to how you think it could be made more efficient. I'll admit it uses more concise syntax (I tried to incorporate what you had written) but don't let that fool you into thinking it's somehow faster in execution.

Comment: worst case you are always going to have to compare every element from the non-key1 lists against all of the elements in the key1 list. The only optimization you can do is break out of the check once you hit a match (which is what I did). Using Linq notation doesn't change this fact.

Answer (score 1):

```
var key1Values;
if (!vertices.TryGetValue("Key1", out key1Values)) {   
   return; 
}

foreach(KeyValuePair<string, ArrayList> entry in vertices)
{
    if((entry.Key == "Key2" || entry.Key == "Key3") && entry.Value.Any(item => key1Values.Contains(item) )
    {
       //do some work
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
var keys =
    vertices
        .Where(y => y.Key != "Key1")
        .Where(y => vertices["Key1"].Cast<string>().Intersect(y.Value.Cast<string>()).Any())
        .Select(x => x.Key);
```

Or, if you change `ArrayList` to `List<string>`:

```
var keys =
    vertices
        .Where(y => y.Key != "Key1")
        .Where(y => vertices["Key1"].Intersect(y.Value).Any())
        .Select(x => x.Key);
```

Comment: correct me if I am wrong but aren't you comparing every list in the dictionary against every other list? OP was only asking to compare the first list against all other lists. For instance, we don't want to find the intersection of lists 2 and 3 as this is unnecessary.

Comment: Also it would result in duplicate matches as 1 - 2 intersection is the same as 2-1 intersection.

Comment: @LucasKot-Zaniewski - You are correct. I've fixed the answer.